# Can I use the RTF format?

Tags: editor, rtf

I am making a text editor and I want to support rtf text files. I want my editor to create RTF text documents and read them. I was doing research and I read that Microsoft developed the rtf format. Can I make this editor without paying any royalties or getting into legal trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the editor.

Microsoft allows use of the file format under its Open Specification Program, which states that:

"Microsoft irrevocably promises not to assert any Microsoft Necessary Claims against you for making, using, selling, offering for sale, importing or distributing any implementation to the extent it conforms to a Covered Specification (“Covered Implementation”), subject to the following. This is a personal promise directly from Microsoft to you, and you acknowledge as a condition of benefiting from it that no Microsoft rights are received from suppliers, distributors, or otherwise in connection with this promise." ([quoted from here](http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/osp/default.aspx))

Among the covered specifications are "Other Office File Formats", among which are RTF ([document found here](http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/osp/default.aspx#office-file-formats)).

You do not need to notify Microsoft for use of these formats.

Comment: Do I need to notify Microsoft?